# How do I pass an expression into jQuery .css method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I got N of `li`.
And an element inside of li that needs to take a width depending on how many `li` there will be.

Here's what I get

```
var breadcrumb = $( '#crumbs ul li a' );
var bradcrumbCounter = $( '#crumbs ul li' );

breadcrumb.css("width", )
```

breadcrumbCounter.length returns 2.

I was planning to use it like in SASS, for example:

```
var widthCalculator = (100 / breadcrumbCounter.length) * 1%;
```

and insert it after "width", so that the width is set depending on the amount of li elements.

```
breadcrumb.css("width", widthCalculator);
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Where am I wrong?

**UPDATE**

Solved:

```
breadcrumb.css( {width: 100 / breadcrumbCounter.length + '%'} );
```

Comment: @qamyoncu ya, just came to solution myself. thank u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var widthCalculator = (100 / breadcrumbCounter.length) * .01;
```

not

```
var widthCalculator = (100 / breadcrumbCounter.length) * 1%;
```

Cannot use % this way...